# Microsoft 365 native and web shared auth

Tags: ios, azure, office365

So I have a product that is on two platforms, web & iOS. My intention is fro the user to be able to log in to Microsoft365 through both platforms, and once done, I can use the access & refresh token to pull some data from their calendar, contacts,etc using a service I have built on the web.

## Attempted Solution #1

Setting the native apps `clientId` to that of the web applications Azura clientId doesn't work, because the authorization context requires a `clientSecret` and there is no place that I have find to supply that.

## Attempted Solution #2

Trying the reversal (giving the web app the `clientId` of the native app) doesn't work as well since native apps on Azure don't have `clientSecrets`s.

For the native app, I'm using the `ADALiOS` framework.

Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to register one app and both the native and web app could use that, or login one app(web or native), and the other app can login directly without entering credentials ?

Comment: The first scenario you described

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure AD does not support registering the Mobile platform and Web platform in one App, you need to register them in separate apps.
[image]
However, the app registers on https://apps.dev.microsoft.com supports multiple platforms.

[image]

For more information about App Model 2.0, please the refer the article as following:

[Active Directory App Model v2.0 Overview](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-appmodel-v2-overview/)